# Git LFS - How to remove older versions of files from a git repository?

Tags: git

I have a Git repository with several huge files. I am using Git LFS for large file support.

Today I received an email saying

```
Git LFS has been disabled on your personal account.... 

Current usage as of 19 May 2019 06:12AM UTC:

Bandwidth: 0.0 GB / 1 GB (0%)
Storage: 6.16 GB / 1 GB (616%)
```

The repository certainly does not have files of 6.26GB. However, possibly Git is adding up storage due to the older versions of file.

Can you help me how do I remove the previous version of files, only keeping the latest?

Comment: Git allows you to go back to old versions of the file, as it existing well before the 19th of May. You can't really remove old versions of the file, to keep only the latest, while still retaining the ability to view those old commits. That's the whole point of Git. I'm not sure of the exact specifics of how git works, but from memory it stores the differences between snapshots of files, and compresses everything as much as possible. someone more knowledge can probably point you in the correct direction. or you could delete the git repo and start over, that would solve ur prob

Comment: `git-lfs prune` will prune old files (**warning** this is a desctructive operation). See `PruneOffsetDays` and the documentation for more info.

Answer (score 6):

My problem is related, but not exactly the same.

I'm using JFrog Artifactory for Git LFS. We have plentiful storage, so storing past versions is not a problem on our "origin".

The problem is with the clone on my PC. I don't need all past versions there - but they pile up every time I `push` or `pull`. This takes up space in the `.git\lfs\objects` folder in the clone - and indeed filled up my drive!

As Aaron Voelkner pointed out in the answer, I can run `git-lfs prune` and it drastically reduces the amount of data stored locally.

```
$ git-lfs prune
prune: 2914 local object(s), 975 retained, done.
prune: Deleting objects: 100% (1939/1939), done.
```

If I wanted to look at older versions, I can still get them via origin, but this makes my local working much simpler.